# How find to whether my Chrome extension was called by shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with a popup that can also be opened by a shortcut. When the popup gets opened, can I find out whether the user has used the shortcut or whether they have clicked on the extension icon?

The reason is that I'd like to hint users to use the shortcut, but I don't want to show that hint to users who already know and use the shortcut.

Popup and shortcut are defined like this in `manifest.json`:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon48.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_tooltip__"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Space"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
```

Not available, because:

> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire
>   if the browser action has a popup.

We has `popup`.

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener
```

Not available, because:

> The '_execute_browser_action' and '_execute_page_action' commands are
>   reserved for the action of opening your extension's popups. They won't
>   normally generate events that you can handle.

May try inject press listener to some page and track pressed of keys (on each page).

---

```
var isPressed;

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {

    if (!(e.keyCode != 17) || !(e.keyCode != 16) || !(e.keyCode != 32)) return;

    isPressed = true;

});
```

From `popup` in moment expand send message to `content_scripts`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "isPressed"}, function (responce) {

        if (responce) {

        }
    });
});
```

After message receiving, listener in content scripts send variable `isPressed` as response:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, response) {

    if (message.action == "isPressed") {

        response(isPressed);
    }
});
```

If variable is true, means called via keystrokes, else on click on icon.

Answer (score 2):

> can I find out whether the user has used the shortcut or whether they
>   have clicked on the extension icon?

There seems to be no clean direct way of detecting that.

Since I put some effort into trying to find a workaround, I would like to share what I have considered/tried and reasons why it doesn't work:

1. Attach the keyboard shortcut to some custom command, modify popup page and then open it programmatically.

   - Doesn't work because there is no way to open the popup programmatically, at least not in current stable version of Chrome (v50).
2. Create a custom command with the same shortcut as "_execute_browser_action" and use it to send a message to the popup.

   - Doesn't work because two commands cannot share the same shortcut.
3. Try to capture `keyup` in the popup page immediately after loading.

   - I tested this and it seemed to work at first, but it is definitely not reliable. If the user only presses the keyboard shortcut very briefly, the `keyup` event is fired before the popup page gets a chance to register a listener for it.
4. Capture `keydown` on pages using a content script and then send a message to the popup page to let it know that the keyboard shortcut was pressed (as suggested by UserName above).

   - This should work on most pages, but the content script won't be able to capture the keypress in address bar and on certain pages (`chrome://`, `chrome-extension://`).
   - Difficult to implement because you need to take into account the fact that users can customize the shortcut on `chrome://extensions` page. Finding the currently assigned shortcut programmatically to test against it in the content script is surprisingly difficult, because `chrome.commands.getAll()` provides localized key names (eg. `"Ctrl+Shift+Space"` in English, but `"Ctrl+Shift+Mezera"` in Czech) There are languages where even Ctrl and Shift don't stay in English.